# Dynamically Increment Variable Name in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AJAXToolkit Accordion control and dynamically adding panes to it based on a query of the database. For example:

Jane logs in and pulls up the page with the accordion on it. In the database she has five rows in the todo_list table. So, I need to dynamically generate five panes that contain the info. from the table...but if Joe logs in he may have only three rows, and Josh may have fifteen - so I can never know how many an individual will have beforehand.

So, I need some way to dynamically name the variables (or is there another way to do this). For example, here is some pseudo-code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Dim i as integer
For each row in todo_list
   Dim ap + i as New AccordionPane
   Add some info from the row to the pane
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create new variable names. You can simply add the newly created AccordionPane object to another object (like a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Y13062))

**EDIT**: Seeing as how the AccoridonPane is a managed control, I would suggest using a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) control to hold your `Accordion` control, dynamically add AccordionPanes to the Accordion control and then add the Accordion to the PlaceHolder:

```
Dim accordion as New AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion    

For each row in todo_list
    Dim ap as New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane
    'Add the row data to the AccordionPane

    accordion.Panes.Add(ap)
Next

'placeHolder is the id of your PlaceHolder control on the page.
placeHolder.Controls.Add(accordion)
```

Comment: When I do Dim accordions As New List(Of AccordionPage) I get an error "Type 'AccordionPage' is not defined"

Comment: @davemackey - I've updated my answer to show a possible solution for dynamically adding an Accordion control to your page.